# Lyrics app with Melody

Tags: release-juno, appcenter, music, elementary-project

I have discoverd Lyrics app recently, it looks great.
But I have a big issue: the Lyric's window is empty when Melody is playing a song.
Lyrics knows a song is played but no lyrics are displayed.

I tried with Give Me Lyrics: it isn't aware when Melody is playing a song... :/

Any idea?
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To speed things up, you may want to report this issue directly to [Lyrics](https://github.com/naaando/lyrics/issues) or [Give Me Lyrics](https://github.com/muriloventuroso/givemelyrics/issues) developers.